Azure Functions + .NET8(Isolated Mode) + OIDC - How to validate an Access Token received in the Header of every request to my Azure Function?
Currently, I'm studying a little about Azure Functions with .NET 8 and OpenId Connect, so I'm currently using a Function [Get] whose response is just an object indicating any valid return (Ex.: Protected Route, 200). What I need to do is for the Access Token (JWT) added in the request Header to be validated so that the request can be processed. Could anyone help me with examples, valid links?
Thank you very much in advance...
I looked for a way to develop Middleware to validate the access token, but I didn't find anything on the internet or in the community that would help me with this or any other way to solve the problem.

Check if this article helps.

To better assist you, could you please provide more details about what you've already tried to solve the issue? Any code snippets, error messages, or specific steps you've taken so far would be helpful. This information will help the community better understand your problem and provide more accurate solutions.

@LuanSouza-DevLuanS0, please check if the solution below helped you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.

Follow below steps to validate an Access Token received in the Header in the Isolated Azure functions.

Create a new App registration in the Microsoft Entra ID.
Navigate to Manage=>Authentication in the App => provide a Redirect URI and check both Access token and ID tokens to be issued as shown below:


Redirect URI:
https://localhost:<port_number>/.auth/login/aad/callback

Install the packages in the Azure function:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
Microsoft.Identity.Web


Thanks @Try Catch Debug for the code.

Use below code to validate the access token:

Update ClientID, Client Secret, Tenant ID, provider

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();        
        services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
       .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
        {
          options.Authority = "https://your-openid-connect-provider.com/Tenant_ID/V2.0";
          options.ClientId = "client-id";
          options.ClientSecret = "client-secret";
          options.ResponseType = "code";
          options.Scope.Add("openid");
          options.Scope.Add("profile");
          options.Scope.Add("email");
          options.SaveTokens = true;
          options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
          options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = "name",
                RoleClaimType = "role"
            };
        });
    })
    .Build();
host.Run();

Code to validate access token:
var openIdConnectHandler = new OpenIdConnectHandler();

await openIdConnectHandler.InitializeAsync(request);
await openIdConnectHandler.ValidateTokenReceptionAsync(request);
await openIdConnectHandler.HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync(request);
await openIdConnectHandler.HandleAuthenticationAsync();

Function.cs:
var claimsPrincipal = executionContext.GetHttpContext().User;

if (!claimsPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    return new UnauthorizedResult();
}

var name = claimsPrincipal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;
var email = claimsPrincipal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value;

return new OkObjectResult(new
{
    Name = name,
    Email = email
});


Where would I put the "Code to validate access token"?
I have this unique problem that my identity provider does not require a client secret, but it does require some custom parameters in the authentication url. I cannot get authentication to work using configuration (plus I want to debug locally), so I'm trying it programmaticly, like in a web app where it works.
